# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: container.init is not a function TypeError: container.init is not a function

Tags: angular

I am having an issue with angular version 13 with module federation version 14.2.0 but I faced this error
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: container.init is not a function
TypeError: container.init is not a function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOWhs.png)

I want to acces my 2nd project moule

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.